# Vue.js, Old style carousel example

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there any way to implement the following carousel in Vue2. Link :
[Image Carousel](https://codepen.io/smitray/pen/qjXGZp)

```
// Parent component
<div class="col">
  <slider>
    <slide v-for="intro in compOpts.blockIntro">
      <block-intro :compOpts="{ props: { wrapper: true, bg: false } }">
        <p v-html="intro.title"></p>
        <div slot="content" v-html="intro.content" class="blockIntro__content"></div>
      </block-intro>
    </slide>
  </slider>
</div>

// Slider component
<div class="slider__container">
  <slot></slot>
</div>

// Slide component
<div>
 <slot></slot>
</div>

// BlockIntro component
<div class="col--h100" :class="{ 'bg--darkDark': compOpts.props.bg, 'col': !compOpts.props.wrapper }">
<div class="col col__blockIntro" :class="{ 'col__blockIntro--spaced': compOpts.props.spaced }">
  <div class="col col__blockIntro__introQuote">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
  <slot name="content"></slot>
</div>
```

My Slide component is giving me the BlockIntro component template and div.col--h100 is the first/parent child element inside Slider. Now I'm trying to add an visible class to div.col--h100 from the Slider component. I consoled the Vnode using $slots but can't change the value in $slots.$elm.className

Please help.

Comment: What's different from yesterday's question?

Comment: Nothing much but can you please elaborate how can I achieve it? I get that you suggested me to use scoped slots but some example which is little bit similar to my requirement, would be a real help.

Comment: I would encourage you to refine your existing, mostly identical question, with details, work you have done already, and/or ask questions on answers supplied there if there are things you don't understand.